# Is there any light ftl lib contains bad block management and wear leveling for nand flash on embeded platform?

Tags: stm32

Is there any light ftl lib contains bad block management and wear leveling for nand flash on embeded platform?
I am using a 512MB nand flash but confused of how to betterly drive it.

Comment: A simple search shows up many results.
some of them:
https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/littlefs-high-integrity-embedded-fs/#:~:text=Wear%2Dleveling,-Most%20storage%20chips&text=The%20embedded%20file%20system%20provides,stored%20in%20the%20file%20system.

https://embedded-access.com/products/flash-file-system/